# Cannot toggle Bluetooth at all in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, 22.04, bluetooth, steam

I've come across a ton of posts on this similar topic and have tried all kinds of different things to get this to work but I'm just not having any luck.

I'm trying to get an 8bitdo wireless controller to connect to my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop computer. It uses a USB dongle to connect. I've tested with a wireless mouse and that works fine, however I can't get Steam to recognize my wireless controller. Most of the tutorials I've found say to scan for nearby Bluetooth devices, however I can't get the toggle on my Bluetooth Manager to turn on. The bluetooth system is started and running, and the controller is recognized by my system

No Bluetooth Found, Can't Toggle On or Off
[image: No Bluetooth Found]

Bluetooth Service is running:
[image: Bluetooth Service is running]

Wireless Controller is recognized when I run `lsusb` command:
[image: Wireless Controller is recognized]

I also seem to have to start the bluetooth service from the command line after each reboot, which is becoming a real pain. I have no idea if that's related or not, but I figured I'd first try to get Bluetooth Manager toggle from my settings working, and maybe I can make some progress from there.

Comment: Check if you can get any life signs from your dongle and device using `bluetoothctl` in similar manner as the GPS is accessed here: https://superuser.com/a/1742028/346288, add any new findings in your post - **edit** it in.

Comment: Looks like that device is supported in 6.3 kernels

Comment: This is some kind of wireless joystick/gamepad?

Comment: @Hannu i've tried bluetoothctl as well. It works to an extent, but I keep getting the "No default controller available" error

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes this is a wireless gamepad. 8bitdo 2.5gz with a dongle to be exact. Dongle seems to be working fine, controller turns on and everything

Comment: Wireless is not necessarily equal to bluetooth, unless stated to be so. based on Jeremy's commet I'd say you have a (required) driver present in kernel 6.3. Without that driver you might not be able to get it running; unless you can find it as a separate package somewhere.

Comment: What kernel is being used, I might be able to patch a driver `uname -r`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
My USB dongle was plugged in, worked as soon as ubuntu was done installing.
On the first reboot it just died.
It would be listed on `lsusb` but nothing else in the system.

I noticed that running `dmesg -w` would show me the USB dongle when unplugging and plugging it back it from the USB port.

Dug around (a lot), and found a solution for my case which seems pretty similar to yours (sorry to whomever I don't give credit for this patchwork of commands - I don't really remember where I got them all)

```
sudo uname -r
#My version is currently 6.5.0-14-generic. Adjust yours below
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic

sudo modprobe -v btusb
```

This is the output of the modprobe command:

> insmod /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btmtk.ko
> insmod
> /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btintel.ko
> insmod /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btbcm.ko
> insmod /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btrtl.ko
> insmod /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko

Final command that got me the bluetooth back:

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb && sleep 10 && sudo modprobe btusb reset=1
```